# VSCode ESLint not giving warnings for unused vars

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, eslint, eslintrc

I have configured my .eslintrc.json as follows...

```
{
  "extends": "eslint:recommended",
  "env": {
    "node": true,
    "es6": true
  },
  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaVersion": 2017
  },
  "rules": {
    "no-unused-vars": "warn"
  }
}
```

and my test.js file simply contains the following line...

```
var blah = "foo";
```

This line is showing no warning.

I do receive other ESLint errors, so I know it is working.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the rest of the options or at least upgrade it from "warn" to "error".

```
{
    "rules": {
        "no-unused-vars": ["error", { "vars": "all", "args": "after-used", "ignoreRestSiblings": false }]
    }
}
```

https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/no-unused-vars